# Apollo Client updateQuery Missing field [fieldName] in {}

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

On a specific Query subscribeToMore function I can't seem to get the Query to take the new data.

```
        updateQuery: async (prev, { subscriptionData } ) => {
            const posts = [
                ...prev.getPosts,
                subscriptionData.data.postCreated
            ];
            const result = {
                ...prev,
                count: posts.length,
                getPosts: posts
            }
            return result;
        }
```

This results in the following error:

> Missing field getPosts in {}

If I log the result I get:

> Object { getPosts: (3) […], count: 3 }

I'm not sure what is causing this as it seems fine on several other updateQuery calls. This one in particular seems to break.

The queries in question:

```
export const POST_CREATED = gql`    
    subscription postCreated($authorId: ID!){
        postCreated(authorId: $authorId){
            id, title, createdAt, published
        }
    } `;

export const GET_POSTS = gql`
    query getPosts($authorId: ID!){
        getPosts(authorId: $authorId){
            id, title, createdAt, published
        }
    } `;
```

Comment: That looks a bit odd -- I wouldn't expect `count` to be at the root level. What's the actual query in question?

Comment: Simply a getPosts query, such that it returns [Post!]. I've ensured the Post responses contain the same information.

Comment: Can you humor me and edit the question to include the actual query? I suspect the object your returning doesn't match your actual query, but I can't confirm that without seeing the query

Comment: Done. The interesting thing is that even if I simply edit the updateQuery to immediately return prev (such that the data is the same) it still results in the same error.

Comment: Yeah, very weird indeed. I believe that error gets thrown when you attempt a write where a query was cached but the [field you're writing isn't in the cache](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/ed66999bac40226abfeada8d6c83b454636bb4b0/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory/src/writeToStore.ts#L208). Are there any mutations that are also updating that same query in the cache? I'm wondering if a `writeQuery` elsewhere in your code is messing up the cache.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same kind of Problem.
I fixed it because the return Object was wrong.
Since you´re only adding the post to the end this should work:

```
updateQuery: async (prev, { subscriptionData } ) => {
        prev.getPosts.push(subscriptionData.data.postCreated)
        return prev;
    }
```